# Python ctypes.create_string_buffer Problem

Tags: python, ctypes

The ReadProcessMemory function of kernel32.dll appears to be returning Unicode.

```
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010

pid = int(raw_input("Enter PID: "))
hproc = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |PROCESS_VM_READ, False, pid)
lpbaseaddr = 16799644
read_buff = ctypes.create_string_buffer(4)
bytread = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(hproc, lpbaseaddr, read_buff,
                               4, ctypes.byref(bytread))
print read_buff.raw #i also tried read_buff.value
```

I know the value at that address is 80 because I used cheat engine to make it 80. The `print read_buff` line returns
`P`. If I make the value of that address 81 with cheat engine and run my program it returns the value `Q`. I have been messing around and `unichr(80)` returns `P` and `unichr(81)` returns `Q`. There is obviously a problem with `create_string_buff`. Should I be using a byte buffer or integer buffer and how would I do that? Using `unichr()` works for a few values but say the address value is `800`, `unichr(800)` obviously won't work. I'm looking for `read_buff` to return `50` or `60` or `800`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not returning Unicode, but four bytes as a string (probably '\x80\x00\x00\x00')  Pass a pointer to an integer not a string buffer:

```
read_buff = ctypes.c_uint()
kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(hproc, lpbaseaddr, ctypes.byref(read_buff),
                           ctypes.sizeof(read_buff), ctypes.byref(bytread))
print read_buff.value
```

Comment: thank you so much mark it worked perfectly, thats exactly the answer i was looking for :) one last question tho, the read_buff = ctypes.c_uint() will that hold any size variable? unlike the string buffer where i had to specify 4 bytes long etc.. thanks again for the fast reply

Comment: ok one last question.. say i wanted to return that byte string. eg "\x80\x00\x00\x00". what pointer would i use then?

Comment: No, `c_uint` is 4 bytes in size, `ctypes.sizeof` returns the size.  `print repr(read_buff.raw)` will display the string in escaped format.

Comment: sigh every time i push enter it sends... anyway.. heres my code.. read_buff = ctypes.create_string_buffer(4)   print repr(read_buff.raw)  this returns "\x90\x00\x00\x00" for example. then using the struct module i go   struct.unpack("i", "\x90\x00\x00\x00") and it gives me the integer i want :) but now how do i get the string version? say for example at that address the value could be an int or a str of a word and i want to try both possible options to see which might contain the value im looking for... thanks

Comment: If it is a string just use create_string_buffer like you were using, and `print read_buff.value`.